# Setting a String in a point Class then using it in a driver class

Tags: java

I am having trouble creating a program for class. I am supposed to get the name and age of a dog then print it's age, name, and age in human years (dog age * 7)
My problem occurs when I try to set the dog's name in the point class then use it in the driver class. I have included my point class, Dog, and my driver class, Kennel.

Point Class: Dog

```
public class Dog 
{

private double age;
private String name;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constructor
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Dog() 
{

}

public Dog(double age)
{
    this.age = age;
}
public void setAge(double age)
{
    this.age = age;
}
public double getAge(double age)
{
    return age;
}
public Dog(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
public void setName(String dogName)
{
    dogName = this.name;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public double personYears()
{
    return age * 7;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Dog's Name: " + name + " Dog's Age: " + age + " Dog's age in person years: " + personYears();
}
```

}

Driver Class: Kennel

```
public class Kennel
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Dog dog1 = new Dog();
    Dog dog2 = new Dog();
    Dog dog3 = new Dog();

    dog1.setAge(5.0);
    dog2.setAge(6.0);
    dog2.setAge(7.0);

    dog1.setName(Spike);
    dog2.setName(Shelby);
    dog3.setName(Brutus);

    System.out.println(dog1.toString());
    System.out.println(dog2.toString());
    System.out.println(dog3.toString());


}
```

}

It doesn't show it on the code but when I try to run the driver class i get an error with the dog.setName methods. It says that Spike cannot be resolved to a variable and so on and so forth with the others. The age part works its just the names I'm having problems with.

Any and all help is appreciated. I have searched around and cannot find anything that relates to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: `Dog.getAge(int age)` - you don't need a parameter for `getAge()`. Sounds like you are missing quote on your calls to `setName`, but without seeing the code who can tell?

Comment: Strings are to be within double quotes like "Spike". More on that here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: I just added parentheses to the names but now the output says Dog's Name: null.

Comment: Check your method setName. `dogName = this.name` is wrong way - reverse the sides.

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize that the order mattered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines of code are errors. Where have you told the compiler what these variables are?

```
dog1.setName(Spike);
dog2.setName(Shelby);
dog3.setName(Brutus);
```

I think what you mean to do is this:

```
dog1.setName("Spike");
dog2.setName("Shelby");
dog3.setName("Brutus");
```

Now, these are not identifiers, but they're string literals. Also, your setter is incorrect.

```
public void setName(String dogName){
    dogName = this.name;
}
```

This should be:

```
public void setName(String dogName){
    this.name = dogName;
}
```

You don't want to change the local parameter `dogName`, you want to change the `String` field `name`.